# Splash-screen in .NET MAUI for Android 12

Tags: c#, .net, maui, splash-screen, android-12

I am developing a small application in `.NET MAUI`. I wanted to set the splash-screen, which I succeeded, but it seems to fail on `Android 12` phones. It works on other versions **both in emulator and physical devices**, but its not working on physical devices with Android 12. For emulators with Android 12, it shows the app icon, which is fine for my use-case.

Having some `Xamarin Forms` background, I attempted to do it the old style, by setting it in the Android namespace, however it seems not to consider any changes I do there. I followed some threads on `github` where they had the same issue: [[1]](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9794) & [[2]](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12636), but nothing seems to be working, although they closed the tickets as being solved. Is there anyone who encountered this and managed to find a solution as well? Thank you!

**Update**:
I tried adding a custom splash-screen the following way:
Under **Platforms/Android/Resources**, I added a folder named **drawable** where I put the image (named 'my_splash.png') I want as splash-screen (with 288x288 px resolution). Inside the **Resources/values** I created a **styles.xml** folder, where I added the following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomSplashTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/my_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, in **MainActivity.cs** I changed the main theme:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/CustomSplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
}
```

It sees the color I set in the style, so I assume the style is correctly set. Maybe something about the image is not properly set. I will try different formats (PNG, SVG) and different dimensions and maybe place the image in resolution-specific folders.

**Edit**: tried placing the file with the appropriate dimensions (and setting every file as **Android Resource**) in all mipmap (**ldpi** up to **xxxhdpi**) as PNGs or SVGs, the splash screen is still not displayed.

Comment: The android 12 has changed the api about the splash screen. And did you check the [splash screen in the maui on the android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android)?

Comment: Since the android 12.0, some kinds of splash screen is not supported such as a full screen image.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I went through Microsoft's documentation on splash-screens, also read the Android documentation. However, it seems that setting those new values in a custom-made styles.xml (as we did in Xamarin Forms) will not be applied at runtime, still getting a solid color background.

Comment: I created a new maui project and run it on the physical device and the emulator which android version is 13.0. The image will show in the splash screen. And you said `custom-made styles.xml`, did you set it as the mainactivity's style?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I am sorry if I explained something wrong, the Android version I have problems with is Android 12.0 (API version 31). For any other version (< 12.0 or > 12.0) it seems to be working. Also, maybe I did not set something when creating the custom styles.xml (as the MainActivity's style), will try again soon

Comment: You said `it only shows the splash screen for emulators with Android 12 (not working on physical devices)`, did you try some other physical device which android version is 12.0?

Comment: Yes, tried 2 phones with Android 12 each, none worked

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Updated the question with what I tried since yesterday.

Comment: Please directly implement the `Maui.SplashTheme` by `parent="Maui.SplashTheme"`. That seems will be ignored. You can custom your full style by the [source code of the `Maui.SplashTheme`](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml).

Comment: If you mean to make my theme inherit from the Maui.SplashTheme, I already do this (as it can be seen in the code from the post, when I define the style). Also I am setting the 2 attributes of the SplashTheme style from your source code. As I said, the color I set in the style is configured, so the image has an issue.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I also realized the splash screen appearing on emulators with Android 12 is actually the app icon, when launched from the home screen (when launched from debugger it does not show).

Comment: Sorry for my careless, it's `don't directly implement the Maui.SplashTheme by parent="Maui.SplashTheme" `. You can copy all the code I provided in the link to your custom style and change the `Maui.SplashTheme` to `CustomSplashTheme`.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Still doesn't work. I also tried defining the other references you have in the code (maui_splash.xml and maui_splash_image.xml, under the styles folder) or using the name of my splash image (i.e. my_splash instead of maui_splash), but still no success

Comment: Did you mean you change the background color successfully but the icon not show?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes. The style is applied, the color I am setting in the style is applied as the background color of the splash-screen. However, the image/logo is not shown. On Android 12 emulators, it shows the app icon, which is fine for my use-case

Comment: You can try to report it as an new issue on the github.